# Como criar um botão toggle on e toggle off?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tenho visto que em alguns cadastros, estão usando muito o botão *toggle*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém saberia como faz isso?

Comment: Uma sugestão sem a tag `<label>` e mais simplificada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277235/3635

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sugiro separar a pergunta em duas e ter uma pergunta à parte para a parte do servidor. Aí creio aliás que há bastantes exemplos de como fazer.

> **Nota:** Acabei por fazer [um componente destes em React no Github](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/react-onoff-switch)

A parte do lado do cliente podes fazer como no exemplo em baixo:

```js
var estado = document.getElementById('estado');
$('#onoff1').on('change', function() {
    var el = this;
    estado.innerHTML = el.checked ? 'ligado' : 'desligado';

    // aqui podes juntar a lógica do ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: "some.php",
        data: {
            estado: this.checked
        }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        if (msg == 'failed') return el.checked = !el.checked; // caso o servidor retorne "failed" mudar o estado do botão
        else alert("Info gravada: " + msg);
    });
});
```

```css
.onoff input.toggle {
    display: none;
}

.onoff input.toggle + label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 1px #d5d5d5;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.onoff input.toggle + label:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: rgba(19, 191, 17, 0);
    transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.onoff input.toggle + label:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.onoff input.toggle:checked + label:before {
    width: 100px;
    background: #13bf11;
}

.onoff input.toggle:checked + label:after {
    left: 40px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #13bf11, 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="onoff">
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="onoff1">
    <label for="onoff1"></label>
</div>

<p id="estado">desligado</p>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d2a9vLpj/

A parte de mudar e colorir o botão é somente HTML + CSS. O JavaScript seria somente para saber quando o botão muda e enviar para o servidor.

Comment: O problema maior é saber se o servidor reconheceu o comando (por exemplo, caso o Ajax não tenha sucesso, ou o servidor ativamente recuse a mudança, seja por permissão ou qq outra coisa, restaurar o toggle na posição anterior). Eu percebo que esse é um dos maiores problemas nestas aplicações Ajax, e nas com angular e similares. A pessoa acha que mudou o dado pelo feedback na tela, mas no servidor ainda está o dado antigo.

Comment: @Bacco bem visto. Acho que esta pergunta devia separar a lógica do servidor e browser. Vou juntar essa lógica na parte do browser.

Comment: @Bacco essa também é uma boa variante. Seria possivel também juntar um debounce  para evitar demasiados cliques e permitir baralhar o resultado. Vou esperar o comentário do AP entretanto.

Comment: Parabéns @Sergio grande resposta +1

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Apenas uma dúvida em relação a ficar enviando dados desta forma para o servidor. E o flood, como fica? Mesmo com um debounce, ainda é possível, e sem um "submit", mesmo que por ajax, não teria como usar nenhum captcha (já que as requisições são enviadas por um simples on/off). Ao meu ver a única saída é um limite de requests, mas aí começamos a complicar o que poderia ser simplificado apenas com um botão "enviar".

Comment: @RenanCavalieri um captcha é uma opção, diria que mais indicado quando a mudança on/off é "definitiva". Um debounce para impedir cliques multiplos demasiado imediatos é também uma opção. Depende de caso para caso, mas pessoalmente acho que elementos que mudam de aparência visualmente (este, um select ou um checkbox) não devem ser manipulados e impedidos de mudar de estado, por questão de UX.

Answer (score 8):

Um exemplo com CSS puro seria assim https://codepen.io/andreasstorm/pen/ZGjNwZ, fiz uma versão mais simplificada https://codepen.io/brcontainer/pen/RpdgLz, o legal dele é que funciona conforme o atributo (propriedade) `checked` e `disabled` assim adaptando o comportamento `:checked` e `:disabled`

Ficando assim:

```css
body {
    background: #eee;
}

.toggle {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.toggle > input {
    display: none;
}

.toggle > label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 44px;
    background: #898989;
    border-radius: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.toggle > label:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    top: -3px;
    display: block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    content: '';
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.toggle > label:active:after {
    transform: scale(1.15, 0.85);
}
.toggle > input:checked ~ label {
    background: #6fbeb5;
}
.toggle > input:checked ~ label:after {
    left: 20px;
    background: #179588;
}
.toggle > input:disabled ~ label {
    background: #d5d5d5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.toggle > input:disabled ~ label:after {
    background: #bcbdbc;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="foo">
    <label for="foo"></label>
</div>

<div class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="bar" checked>
    <label for="bar"></label>
</div>

<div class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="baz" disabled>
    <label for="baz"></label>
</div>
```

### Versão semelhante ao iOS

Para ficar semelhante ao iOS

```css
body {
    background: #eee;
}

.toggle {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.toggle > input {
    display: none;
}

.toggle > label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 52px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border: 1px #a2e3e6 solid;
    border-radius: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.toggle > label:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    display: block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    content: '';
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.toggle > label:active:after {
    transform: scale(1.15, 0.85);
}
.toggle > input:checked ~ label {
    background-color: #4cda64;
    border-color: #4cda64;
}
.toggle > input:checked ~ label:after {
    left: 25px;
}
.toggle > input:disabled ~ label {
    background-color: #d5d5d5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.toggle > input:disabled ~ label:after {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="foo">
    <label for="foo"></label>
</div>

<div class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="bar" checked>
    <label for="bar"></label>
</div>

<div class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="baz" disabled>
    <label for="baz"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Bonito esse css. Valeu por compartilhar a sua resposta.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda fico realmente muito agradecido =)