# Como criar um botão de switch igual o do Android com CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Como posso fazer para criar um botão de switch Igual esse do Android com CSS?

É necessário Javascript para fazer o "liga-desliga", ou eu consigo fazer isso somente com CSS?

[image: Switch Igual Android]

Comment: Acho que é mesmo duplicada, o JS que tem na resposta lá não interfere na funcionalidade do on/off. Era isso que procuravas?

Comment: @Sergio o único problema é que eu queria fazer algo que desse pra usar com AngularJS (eu não uso mais jQuery). Vi na internet que alguns fizeram sem Javascript, usando um checkbox com o atributo for (com visibilidade oculta). Seria interessante ter uma resposta dessa aqui, não acha?

Comment: Mas a tua pergunta é _"É necessário Javascript para fazer o "liga-desliga", ou eu consigo fazer isso somente com CSS?"_ se vires bem na resposta lá isso é sem JavaScript nenhum: https://jsfiddle.net/o525zr7b/

Comment: Pena queres Angular, hà uns tempos [fiz um em React](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/react-onoff-switch) :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters um exemplo somente com CSS baseado nos atributos (propriedades) HTML, como `checked` e `disabled`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/198805/3635