# Como criar um botão toggle com input=checkbox sem usar o elemento <label>?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

É criar/transformar um `<input type="checkbox">` em um botão toggle sem precisar do elemento `<label>` como nestes exemplos:

- [Como criar um botão toggle on e toggle off?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162291/3635)

Um exemplo que eu fiz baseado no código do [Andreas Storm](https://codepen.io/andreasstorm/pen/ZGjNwZ) foi este:

```css
body {
    background: #eee;
}

.toggle {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.toggle > input {
    display: none;
}

.toggle > label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 52px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border: 1px #a2e3e6 solid;
    border-radius: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.toggle > label:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    display: block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    content: '';
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.toggle > label:active:after {
    transform: scale(1.15, 0.85);
}
.toggle > input:checked ~ label {
    background-color: #4cda64;
    border-color: #4cda64;
}
.toggle > input:checked ~ label:after {
    left: 25px;
}
.toggle > input:disabled ~ label {
    background-color: #d5d5d5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.toggle > input:disabled ~ label:after {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="foo">
    <label for="foo"></label>
</div>

<div class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="bar" checked>
    <label for="bar"></label>
</div>

<div class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="baz" disabled>
    <label for="baz"></label>
</div>
```

Seria possivel criar algo assim sem label e sem qualquer outro elemento (e sem JavaScript também)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É possível usando dois pseudo elementos, o `::before` e o `::after`, também será necessário usar as propriedades `-webkit-appearance:` e `-moz-appearance:` (e no futuro `appearance:`).

No MSEdge antigo (EdgeHTML) e Internet Explorer isso não irá funcionar, já nas versões recentes do Firefox, navegadores WebKit (Safari, iOS e Android) e Chrome (e navegadores baseados em Chromium, incluindo o MSEdge atual)

Deve ficar assim:

```css
/*Adiciona border-box para o input e para os pseudo-elementos*/
input[type=checkbox], input[type=checkbox]::after, input[type=checkbox]::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*Estiliza e remove a aparencia padrão do elemento*/
input[type=checkbox] {
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 48px;
    height: 24px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

/*cria os elementos before e after*/
input[type=checkbox]::before, input[type=checkbox]::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;

    /*efeito animado*/
    transition: left .15s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, .1),
                transform .15s ease-in;
}

/*Cor padrão de quando o elemento não esta selecionado*/
input[type=checkbox]::before {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 28px;
}

/*estiliza para parecer um botão toggle*/
input[type=checkbox]::after {
    margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

/*troca a cor se estiver com a propriedade checked no html ou o usuário "checar"*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked::before {
    background-color: #75a940;
}

/*muda a posição do botão toggle se estiver checado*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked::after {
    left: 24px;
}

/*Efeito opcional de quando pressiona o botão*/
input[type=checkbox]:not([disabled]):active::after {
    transform: scale(1.15, 0.85);
}

/*Se o input tiver com o atributo disabled a cor é alterada*/
input[type=checkbox]:disabled::before {
     background-color: #b1b4b7 !important;
}

/*Se o input tiver com o atributo disabled a cor é alterada*/
input[type=checkbox]:disabled::after {
     background-color: #dcd8d8 !important;
}

/*OUTRAS CORES = Cores alternativas*/

input[type=checkbox].red:checked::before {
     background-color: #fd4554;
}

input[type=checkbox].blue:checked::before {
     background-color: #0f90dc;
}

input[type=checkbox].red:checked::before {
     background-color: #fd4554;
}

input[type=checkbox].purple:checked::before {
     background-color: #9e3eff;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="red">
<input type="checkbox" class="blue">
<input type="checkbox" class="purple">
<input type="checkbox" class="purple" disabled>

<hr>

<input type="checkbox" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="red" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="blue" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="purple" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="purple" checked disabled>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenho uma opção similar a do Guilherme, porém eu dou um `all:unset` no *checkbox* primeiro para limpar toda a formatação *default* do `user-agent`

Depois eu estilizo o próprio `input` da forma que quiser e uso apenas o `::after`. Funcionou no Chrome e no FireFox, acredito que no Safari tb vai funcionar. No IE e Edge não fica como o esperado.

**OBS:** Do ponto de vista da acessibilidade, por ser um item de `form` sem `label`, seria interessante atribuir um `aria-label=" "` no *ckeckbox* dizendo do que se trata esse btn. Caso tenha interesse aqui está a recomendação da W3C sobre o assunto https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/

```css
  .btn {
    all: unset;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #f00;
    border-radius: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    transition: background-color 100ms ease-in-out;
  }
  .btn:checked {
    background-color: #090;
  }
  .btn::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background-image: radial-gradient(#fff 0%, #999 100%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 5px;
    transform: translateY(-50%) scale(1, 1);
    transition: left 200ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease-in-out;
  }
  .btn:checked::after {
    left: calc(100% - 25px);
  }
  .btn:active::after {
    transform: translateY(-50%) scale(1.15, 0.85);
  }
```

```html
  <input class="btn" type="checkbox" aria-label="btn seleciona opção x">
```

Comment: Melhor aplicar `all: unset;` a classe `.btn`, pois no caso do exemplo especifico afetaria todos radios, mas só teriam efeitos completos os radios com a classe btn, sendo assim outros radios sem a classe ficaria bugados. Ou então troque a classe .btn pelo seletor do tipo do elemento `[type="checkbox"]` em todos seletores.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim vc tem razão, como estava fazendo em um ambiente de teste nem me atentei a isso, mas já inclui tudo na mesma classe e removi o seletor global do checkbox